# SemanticUI: how to trigger a form validation maually / in modal

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

When a modal window is started, there will be no form validation if you use the default way:

```
  $('#someModalWindow')
        .modal({
            inline: true,
            onDeny: function () {
                // someting
            },
            onApprove: function () {
                // some action
            }
        })
        .modal('show');
```

How can a form validation be triggered manually or automatically in the modal window.

I am using meteor below SemanticUI

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it:

```
 $('#someModalWindow')
    .modal({
        onDeny: function () {
            // someting
        },
        onApprove: function () {
            var validated = $('#myFormId').form('validate form');
            if(!validated){
                return false;
            }
            // some action
        }
    })
    .modal('show');
```

hopefully this can help you.